# Difference of get() and find() in redis-om redisjson

Tags: redis, redis-py

I was wondering why the following 2 examples do NOT return the same.

```
ts = Signal.find(Signal.pk == pk).all()
ts = Signal.get(pk)
```

- The first line returns an empty array. (Only if I restart the FastAPI, after inserting, it returns the values)
- The second line returns the full JsonModel object (as intended).

The Signals was before successfully saved as JSON using the Python OM library for redis https://github.com/redis/redis-om-python. That is `signal.save()` in my case.

Is there anything one needs to consider when saving or querying that record by PK using `find()`?

FYI - the model

```
from enum import Enum
from typing import Optional
from uuid import UUID
from famodels.models.direction import Direction
from famodels.models.side import Side
from redis_om import Migrator
from redis_om import (Field, JsonModel)

class Signal(JsonModel):
    provider_id: str = Field(index=True)
    algo_id: str = Field(index=True)
    provider_signal_id: Optional[str]
    provider_trade_id: str = Field(index=True)
    is_hot_signal: bool = Field(default=False )
    market: str = Field(index=True)
    exchange: str = Field(index=True)
    direction: Direction = Field(index=True)
    side: Side = Field(index=True)
    price: float
    tp: float
    sl: float     

    class Meta:
        global_key_prefix="signal-processing"
        model_key_prefix="raw-signal"
    # class Config:
    #     orm_mode = True

Migrator().run()
```

FastAPI code running the `Migrator().run()` additonally.

```
@app.get("/signals")
async def get_signal():
    logger.debug("get all Signals.")    
    Migrator().run()
    return Signal.find().all()
```

It is interesting to observe, that if I add a new attribute to the Model, and create new records (which I can see under the same index in RedisInsight), they do not show up upon invoking `Signal.find().all()`. As if `find().all()` cannot consider new versions of the model.

Another preculiarity I have noted: Boolean need to be set to False imperatively. Missing out on it returns an empty array. That would imply one cannot search for true/false on that attribute and needs to transform it to 1/0 instead. Very unfortunate.

```
is_hot_signal: bool = Field(default=False, index=False)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`find` uses the Search capability of Redis Stack, so your Redis Server will need to be a Redis Stack one or have the Search module installed.  Additionally, to make `find` work you will need to run Redis OM Python's `Migrator` in order to create a search index in Redis that the search capability will then use to track changes on qualifying data.

The `get` function doesn't use Search, it uses `JSON.GET` for JSON models or `HGET` / `HGETALL` for Hash models.  For this to work, you need the key of the item you want to retrieve.

Additionally I suspect your `find` doesn't return anything as `pk` isn't an indexed value.  To advise further I'd need to see your model class and where you are calling the `Migrator`.

References:

- RediSearch capability: https://redis.io/docs/stack/search/
- Redis OM Python querying and migrator: https://github.com/redis/redis-om-python#querying

Comment: Thank you, Simon. I have restarted the FastAPI again, after I have inserted fresh values - and then it worked. I think you are right, I fail to call the Migrator().run() in the right place. I haven't understood the pattern yet.

Also, it seems that when I add new attributes to the model to which I can successfully add new records, it does NOT fetch these new records (despite I update the FastAPI app with the new model and restart it completely). Very strange.

I have added the model class and how I call the find function in the FastAPI app.

Comment: Is it true, that one cannot use bool to index/search?

Comment: @feder correct - for the moment you'd need to use 1/0 or True/False as tag values

Comment: Good to have that confirmed. And thank you for all the dev work, examples, documentation and so on. It really allows a jaw-dropping fast deep dive into redis (with python). Appreciated.